# On back button click execute a function.

Tags: javascript, jquery

On `document.ready` event I've got a function which collects the html controls which has an attributes 'wordNum' and I make an AJAX request which returns me  some description for each of these controls  and then I set these controls and their `innerhtml` attribute with the returned description.

The problem is if the user clicks back button and this function of course is not executed but I need that.

**Code:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    Translate();
});
function Translate() {
    var list = new Array();
    $("*[wordNum]").each(function () {
        var endRes = {
            ControllerName: this.id,
            WordNumber: this.getAttribute("wordNum")
        };
        list.push(endRes);
    });
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: ' @Url.Action("Translate")',
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
            List: JSON.stringify(list)
        },
        traditional: true,
    }).done(function (data) {
        $.each(data, function (key, val) {
            $("*[wordNum]").each(function () {
                if (this.id == val.ControllerName) {
                    this.innerHTML = val.Description;
                }
            });
        });
    });
}
```

So how can I make on back button click to again execute this function `Translate`.

Comment: Your best solution would be to find a way for your application to work without hooking into the back button event. This isn't an event you can rely on for instance if the user closes the browser or goes to a new url directly.

Also it is a pretty bad UX when you cant leave the site until an api call has finished. I would suggest finding another way!

Comment: I know but unfortunately there is no way!

Comment: The back button implies that the user does not want to continue processing something. You should not make it execute any code. This is way up there with popup that don't go away and email spam on irritation levels. You should change your code so that it does not require this. If you provide more details, maybe we can tell you how to do that?

Comment: if you need a code executed on back button, you should created your own 'back' button and make it clearly visible and intuitive so the user will use it instead of the browser's back button.

Comment: also try using jQuery's `.unload()` to detect when user navigates away from your page and then execute your function. http://api.jquery.com/unload/

Comment: yes you see it right - but that's not my idea. I know it's a very very bad and actually |I can't stand anymore this project but..

Answer (score 4):

You can use popstate event to fire the event:

```
$(window).on("popstate", function (event, state) {
    // Here comes the code to execute when the back button is pressed
} );
```

Comment: It does, but it also triggers on forward button, page refresh and more. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/popstate_event